# Everything goes up when adding iAd banner [SWIFT]

Tags: ios, swift, iad

All the labels, textFields and etc... go up when I add iAd banner(at the bottom of the screen). Is it always like that or can I add it somehow without moving all the stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're implementing your `ADBannerView` using `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`. Implementing your `ADBannerView` in this manner will resize your `UIView` to fit the `ADBannerView` on the bottom of your devices screen.

If you'd like to avoid this you can implement your `ADBannerView` programmatically or through Interface Builder. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31788121/2108547) for a programmatic example to get you started. Don't forget to remove `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` when implementing your own `ADBannerView`.